# Django form field shows item of other field

Tags: django-forms

Why  “car_name”  field shows teacher_name?!!
The car name should be Nissan.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm2uK.png)

```
**forms.py**
class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'
        #exclude = ('owner',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(CarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields[‘car_name'].queryset = TeacherDetails.objects.filter(owner=user)

**models.py**
class TeacherName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TeacherDetails(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(TeacherName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_name = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.teacher_name)
```

I am new to Django and have searched stack overflow but did not find someone talking about it.